# Jenkins pipeline unable to read kubernetes deployment file

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I set up a full CI/CD to build a docker image and deploy it to Kubernetes. Everything runs successfully but, the pipeline fails to find the `deployment.yaml`.

I already installed envsubst.

> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/thop-backend_prod@tmp/durable-86e75e61/script.sh: 1: cannot open Kubernetes/deployment.yml: No such file
>
> - envsubst
> - kubectl apply -f -
>   error: no objects passed to apply
>   [Pipeline] }
>   [kubernetes-cli] kubectl configuration cleaned up

```
    def kubeDeploy(String regName , String imageName , String imageVersion , String clusterCredentials , String url) {
    
    script.withKubeConfig([credentialsId: clusterCredentials, serverUrl: url]) {
        script.sh "envsubst < Kubernetes/deployment.yml | kubectl apply -f -"
        script.sh "envsubst < Kubernetes/service.yml | kubectl apply -f -"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `script.sh`....and why you dont just use `kubectl apply -f Kubernetes/deployment.yml`?

Comment: kubectl apply -f Kubernetes/deployment.yml fails as well.

I look up the path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/thop-backend_prod@tmp/durable-86e75e61/script.sh but, durable-86e75e61/script.sh does not exist.

Comment: My mistake, I think that `script.sh` is part of jenkins. The instructions-commands are ok but it seems that nothing get passed to `envsubst`. Can you add this line at the beginning  `script.sh "cat Kubernetes/deployment.yml` with that it should print the content of your yaml file. If it print nothing then it's because the yaml file is empty or doesn't exist

Comment: Very strange because the kubernetes folder is in the same directory with Jenkinsfile. Yet it is not found.

+ cat Kubernetes/deployment.yml
cat: Kubernetes/deployment.yml: No such file or directory

I'm using the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a problem with not being able to find the file, using `pwd` should give you the path you are currently on and `ls` can show you the list of files and folder present in the path. Use both and see if you are in the correct folder.

If your "Kubernetes" folder is in the workspace folder along with your Jenkinsfile, you could wrap you `script.withKubeConfig` with `dir`:

```
dir($WORKSPACE) {
    script.withKubeConfig([credentialsId: clusterCredentials, serverUrl: url]) {
        script.sh "envsubst < Kubernetes/deployment.yml | kubectl apply -f -"
        script.sh "envsubst < Kubernetes/service.yml | kubectl apply -f -"
    }
}
```

If none of the above works, use `&&` to directly specify the directory where the deployment.yml file can be found:

```
script.withKubeConfig([credentialsId: clusterCredentials, serverUrl: url]) {
    script.sh "cd /path/to/Kubernetes/folder && envsubst < deployment.yml | kubectl apply -f -"
    script.sh "cd /path/to/Kubernetes/folder && envsubst < Kubernetes/service.yml | kubectl apply -f -"
}
```